# Identifier expected issue

Tags: java

I can't seem to find the error here. Apparently, an identifier is expected after "final" for all of the constants. Can somebody help?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Letter
{
    private static final int 30G_PRICE = 40; 
    private static final int 50G_PRICE = 55;  
    private static final int 100G_PRICE = 70; 
    private static final int ADDITIONAL_50G_PRICE = 25;
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    BufferedReader console = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't start a variable (or any other identifier) name with a number.

[From the tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal
>   identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and
>   digits, **beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the
>   underscore character "_".**

Answer (score 1):

Variable names (or names of any other identifier) cannot start with a number.  Try this:

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

```
public class Letter
{
    private static final int PRICE_30G = 40; 
    private static final int PRICE_50G = 55;  
    private static final int PRICE_100G = 70; 
    private static final int ADDITIONAL_50G_PRICE = 25;
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    BufferedReader console = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }   
}
```

Numbers are allowed to be put anywhere else in the identifier.